# How to completely uninstall .NET from macos

Tags: .net, macos

I have installed multiple versions of .NET in my macbook m1 and I want to wipe out all of them so that I can install .NET 6.
Is there a quick way to do it apart from using Terminal?

Comment: Does the [.NET Uninstall Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried even the latest version but it seems there is an issue with M1 processor

Comment: Please provide more explanations. What you have tried? What problems did you face?

Comment: I have used .NET Uninstall Tool and also the homebrew tool

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I intalled the latest version of .NET Uninstall Tool and followed the instructions provided by Microsoft. With Mac OSX  Mojave it worked as a charm!